# Custom php.ini for VirtualHost

Tags: apache2, php, virtualhost

Is there a way to use a different `php.ini` file foreach `VirtualHost` in apache?

I know that there are the `php_admin_values`

```
<Location /stat/>
    php_admin_value safe_mode off
</Location>
```

But i want to specify a full php.ini file for a virtualhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use something like [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html) to achieve this. In addition to running each VirtualHost's php execution as a different user - it allows you to have multiple php.ini files for VirtualHosts and Directories (Based on `.htaccess` `suPHP_Config` flag)

You can install suPHP via aptitude: `sudo apt-get install suphp-common libapache2-mod-suphp` One of the main differences is you can now setup php to be executed as a user - rather than having all php scripts executable by the `www-data` user - this alone provides a lot of convenience and security when hosting multiple users on one server as it cuts down the needs for 777 and 666 permissions (In fact you should never need to use 777 or 666 ever again - 755/644 should always be sufficient)

An example virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...
   DocumentRoot /home/marco/www/
   suPHP_UserGroup marco marco
   suPHP_Config /home/marco/etc/php.ini
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You can also set the suPHP_Config directive in `.htaccess` files - provided you have `AllowOverride` setup properly.